# How to apply logical operator in google amp script?

Tags: amp-html, amp-bind

With reference to Google AMP, I have the following code:

```
<a [href]="'?view=amp&constraint=' + selectedOption1 + '&sort_by=' + selectedSorting"> Submit </a>
```

I would like to display `'?view=amp&constraint='` only if the value of `selectedOption1` exists.

How can I achiieve the same?

I have tried the below:

```
<a [href]="'?view=amp&amp;constraint=' + (selectedOption1 || '') + '&amp;sort_by=' + (selectedSorting || '')" > </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the condition operation on selectedOption1. Here is an example shared for your reference with two buttons, which will change the state of selectedOption1 and accordingly, you can check anchor tag's href value, and for quick view I have used paragraph tag to display same value as href in paragraph. Hope this will help you.

To run this code, copy whole code and replace it with the body part on [here](https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fcomponents%2Famp-bind.example.1.html%3Fformat%3Dwebsites&format=websites&_gl=1*x8sui5*_ga*MTEzOTc4MTIxLjE1ODEwMTMyMzY.)
AMP playground, just make sure that you have imported amp-bind js on amp playground sample page.

```html
<p [text]="selectedOption1 ? 'https://www.example.com?view=amp&constraint=' + selectedOption1 + '&sort_by=' + selectedSorting : 'www.example.com'">

</p>
  <a href="#" [href]="selectedOption1 ? 'https://www.example.com?view=amp&constraint=' + selectedOption1 + '&sort_by=' + selectedSorting : 'https://www.example.com'">
  Link
</a>
 </br>

<button on="tap:AMP.setState({selectedOption1: 'Interactivity',selectedSorting:'orderby_date'})">
  Say "Hello Interactivity"
</button>
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({selectedOption1: '',selectedSorting:''})">
  Say "Blank"
</button>
```

Comment: Just want to confirm - (A ? '1' : '2') , when used in amp like in your example above, implies that if A exists then '1' will be the value else '2' shall be the value?
Also where is this mentioned in the AMP documentation, I would like to see all the operators as well. Cannot fiind it in AMP Bind documentation also.

Comment: Yes, the explanation you had given is correct. You can also have some conditions in that like (A == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No') kind of thing which will compare 'A' value with 1 and give output as per condition.
Here is the link to amp-bind page, you can find each and every operations and attribute  regarding amp-bind https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind/
And regarding this ternary operation, I found this example here, https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/interactivity-dynamic-content/tic_tac_toe/?format=websites.
Hope this will help you.